# zend framework 2 stop radio button groups being wrapped in fieldset

Tags: zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2 Radio buttons are wrapped in a fieldset.

How would I alter this behavior so say they were wrapped in a div?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how it is unclear.
In Zend Framework 2 by default multi checkboxes/radio buttons are wrapped in a fieldset.

I would like to override this with a helper to wrap it instead in a div.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own radio view helper. See here for more information:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html